# My Question is about the prime number code that it display multiple of three

Tags: java

My code is about display all prime number range between number provided to it but the problem is that it display prime number as well as multiple of three.

```
if (number<=1)
{
    System.out.println("your number don't has prime number range");
}
else
{
    for (j=1;j<=number;j++)
    {
        counter=0;
        for (i=2;i<=j;i++)
        {
            if (j%i==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                counter=1;
            }
        }
        if (counter==1)
        {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
}
```

The result of 34 is

```
3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33
```

Comment: multiple of 3 ? can you explain more ?

Comment: It also displays 25. It's not just multiples of 3 that are your problem. It's that you set `counter` to 1 as soon as you find any number that is not a factor (which happens for any odd number).

Comment: just look up how to calculate primes. This is not it.

Comment: This is almost the opposite logic of what you wanted: the flag is set if *at least one* divisibility test failed. Not all of them, just one. If a number of not divisible by 2, it will be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside the loop with j as counter variable. This ensures that all the numbers from 2 to j-1 are not factors of j. Also check on other methods of prime number generation like **Sieve of Eratosthenes**, or reducing the complexity of this code by running loop till `sqrt(j)`

```
counter=0;
for(i=2;i<j;i++){
    if(j%i==0){
        counter=1;
        break;
    }
}
if(counter==0){
    System.out.println(j);
}
```